# Convert Datatable into an array in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I want to convert DataTable in an 2-D array form in C#.
Below is the example for clear understanding.

DataTable in C#:

```
code           Price
----------     ----------
1146441600000  34
1146528000000  5
1146614400000  10
1146700800000  7
1146787200000  12
1147046400000  8
1147132800000  9
```

Output required in js:

```
[[1146441600000,34],
[1146528000000,5],
[1146614400000,10],
[1146700800000,7],
[1146787200000,12],
[1147046400000,8],
[1147132800000,9]]
```

I am using Razor engine for front end rendering.

Comment: What did you try to do? Any code examples? Where did you struggle?

Comment: Sounds great! You can do it

Comment: Do you want to do it in C# or in JavaScript?

Comment: you can use many things, ajax, json, list, enumerable...

Comment: what are you going to do with it after conversion...

Answer (score 2):

Very easy:

```
string[] arrray = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(k => k[0].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This only is for one row how this answer the question as whole table is required to be converted.

Comment: @MairajAhmad you are right, thank you for the comment, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way is using format options and `Linq` extension functions and doing this.

```
DataTable dt; // set your source
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Select(r=> string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", r.ItemArray)));

var output = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", rows.ToArray()));
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dsq2Vj)